# Keypress events in JavaScript & JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an HTML slideshow by myself and was able to create most of the thing. The place where I am stuck is the keyboard events. That is forward and backward arrow. I need to know how to handle these using JavaScript or JQuery. These button when pressed would trigger an event so as to move to the next slide or go to the previous one. I also want to mention that my slides are also interactive HTML, as in you can fill in data, validate etc using them. SO i dont want the keyboard events to hinder while the user is interacting with the form or other content on the page via Keyboard (eg. Filling in a form,date etc).
How to go about this ?

Comment: What is it you need to know beyond using the [`.keypress()` jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 different events for handling keyboard input: keyup, keydown, and keypress. Not all are fired on all keys, and some fire different codes depending on operating system. Check out [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) for more info.

jQuery has corresponding events for each of these.

From [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. **Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.**

To avoid handling these events when user is interacting with the form, you might want to turn the behavior off any time a form field has focus, and turn it back on when the form fields are blurred. That way, using these arrows to navigate an input field wouldn't cause slideshow traversal.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; //browser compatible
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 39:
            alert("right key pressed");
            break;
        case 37:
            alert("left key pressed");
            break;
        default:
            alert("other key pressed");
    }
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3wdw7/

Comment: Hi... I tried out fiddle but I right and left key, did you mean arrow key... they din work. Other keys are working.My soncern is that if I have a text box in the page and I ma typing in it then this code should not work. As I leave the textbox this should start working again http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/HgDAD/ I have a text box where I want to type without hindrance.As I am out of it the script should run

Comment: You'll want to use `keydown` instead of `keypress` here because the goal is to catch arrow keys. See the difference between the two here : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: jQuery [normalizes `event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) — you can just use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.target !== document.body) return;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 39:
        alert("right");
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
    case 37:
        alert("left");
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
});
```

You can check the target of the event to ignore key events on child elements like text fields, and you should probably prevent default on the event to stop the browser from performing its default action, like scrolling the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/3wdw7/2/